# Upload an File in Assets folder of angular application?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I just want to upload and save a file in assets folder without using any server-side scripting or code. Is there any way achieve this?

I don't know any backend and only working in frontend for now and want to handle this without backend scripting

Comment: Not possible without backend.